# How to prevent user go back to protected page after logout

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, android-activity, firebase-authentication

I want user won't access `MainActivity`(HomePage) without login. For that when user open app, `MainActivity` checked if user not login, then he go to `LoginActivity` via `Intent`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

**But 2 issue happen:**

- After app move user to LoginActivity, by pressing Back button user can view Home Page witout login.
- And after Logout user move to Login Page but by pressing Back button user can go to Home Page.

> Please help me to solve this issue.

MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user == null){

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

    mDataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("BlogApp").child("Posts");
    mBlogList = findViewById(R.id.blogListId);
    mBlogList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapterSetUp();
    mBlogList.setAdapter(adapter); // load blog posts

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call `finish()` method after `startActivity` like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: One more questions,  If I aren't add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, `addFlags` then what change will happen?

Comment: you don't need to add flag here  remove this line intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
nothing change in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You should craete a launcher activity which either load the Login activity for unregistered users or main activity for registered ones.
Another way you can achieve what you wish is to create main activity with two fragments, one for your home page and one for the login page, than you can decide which fragment to present.
Hope it helps, good luck!

Comment: I can't got you clearly. I want, "after login usen't can't go LoginActivity by pressing back button and after logout user can't go back to MainActivity by pressing back button".

Comment: i will try to be more clear, you need to create an activity which has no view (i.e don't call setContentView()). this activity purpose would be only to decide which activity to launch(main activity or login activity).  according to the user's status(login or not).

Answer (score 0):

Use `finishAffinity()` method that will finish the current activity and all parent activities. But it works only for `API 16+`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finishAffinity();
```

call`finishAffinity()` method after startActivity.